# Can I just modify the definition from c'gc to cgc'?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've read the answer from here: [Factor Group over Center Isomorphic to Inner Automorphism Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525058/factor-group-over-center-isomorphic-to-inner-automorphism-group)

I would like to comment there but I don't have 50 reputations to comment :(
So I'm writing here.

The definition of an inner automorphism is an automorphism of the form c'gc (' indicates the inverse)
But it seems that he/she just used cgc'. Why is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are equivalent. If you let $d=c'$, then $c'gc=dgd'$.